EnsureOriginBy using an account set on a pallet's storage
I'm working on a feature that requires pallet-nfts ForceOrigin to only be callable by an account configured inside a separated pallet's storage. For example in pallet-A I have the following
#[pallet::storage]
pub type Authority<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, T::AccountId, OptionQuery>;

Now I need to configure pallet-nfts ForceOrigin to take this Authority as the allowed origin. For this I'm trying to use EnsureOriginBy like this
impl pallet_nfts::Config for Runtime {
    ...
    type ForceOrigin = EnsureSignedBy<Authority, AccountId>;
    ...
}

How could I define Authority in the runtime config to get the value in pallet-A storage?
I have an alternative solution which is to define the account directly in the runtime config
pub const Authority: AccountId = AccountId::from(hex_literal::hex!("00000000000000000000000000000000000"));

But this would mean that the only way to change this authority is via a runtime upgrade and not though a call to a setAuthority() extrinsic in pallet-A

type Who in EnsureSignedBy<Who, AccountId> is bounded by SortedMembers trait. Implement this either for your pallet or for a custom struct:
pub struct AuthorityProvider<T: crate::Config>(sp_std::marker::PhantomData);

impl<T: crate::Config> SortedMembers<T::AccountId> for AuthorityProvider<T> {
   fn sorted_members() -> Vec<T::AccountId> {
       if let Some(authority) = Authority::<T>::get() {
           return vec![authority]
       }
       vec![]
   }

   fn contains(who: &T::AccountId) -> bool {
       if let Some(authority) = Authority::<T>::get() {
           return authority == who
       }
       false
   }
}

Then pass it to EnsureSignedBy:
type ForceOrigin = EnsureSignedBy<pallet_a::AuthorityProvider<Runtime>, AccountId>;


This worked flawlessly, thank you

glad it helped. please, upvote or accept as answer :)

You can write your own EnsureOrigin implementation:
struct EnsureAuthority<T>(core::marker::PhantomData<T>);

impl<T> EnsureOrigin<T::RuntimeOrigin> for EnsureAuthority<T> 
where
   T: Config,
   T::RuntimeOrigin: Into<Result<RawOrigin<T::AccountId>, T::RuntimeOrigin>> + From<RawOrigin<T::AccountId>,
{
    type Success = ();
    fn try_origin(o: T::RuntimeOrigin) -> Result<Self::Success, O> {
        match o.clone().into()? {
             RawOrigin::Signed(s) if Authority::<T>::get().map_or(false, |a| a == s) => Ok(()),
             r => Err(r.into()),
        }
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    fn try_successful_origin() -> Result<T::RuntimeOrigin, ()> {
        Ok(Authority::<T>::get().ok_or(())?)
    }
}

